# Is there some way to distinguish between "better" and "worse" political ideologies on some general level?

Tags: political-philosophy

Is there some way to distinguish between "better" and "worse" political ideologies on some general level?

It's clear that there are some subjective beliefs/preferences such as being in favor of labour philosophies, if one belongs to a lower wealth class.

But I also believe that there could be an objective political context, that is, political ideas that should be rational regardless of subjective viewpoint. It would contain the most fundamental and universal beliefs.

But, what/how can one identify things that belong there? Criterion of universality (i.e. how many believe in it), criterion of "hardness" (e.g. that killing is bad), something else?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no" based on Moral Foundation Theory because there are multiple moral foundations that are somewhat contradictory. So there are many ways to be right and many ways to use one's rational ability to justify different political positions. See Jonathan Haidt's *The Righteous Mind*. I'll try to answer this in more detail, but I left the reference in case I don't.

Comment: I agree with @FrankHubeny. One way to judge how "good" something is to determine how well it satisfies its intended goal. Before you can find a good or bad political ideology, you have to decide what a good or bad society is. Is freedom more important than law and order? Is feeding people more important than the concept of personal ownership? And pretty much every other political question in the universe :)

Comment: @barrycarter But then since different people claim to value different things, does that end to an unsolvable chaos? How can one select more objective beliefs among "all beliefs"?

Comment: Can you give an example of a truly objective belief? Remember, people don't even agree on facts. Aside from basic tautologies (and maybe not even those), you can pretty much argue any belief is not completely objective.

Comment: "*Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time*", made famous by Churchill. One could come up with some measures, like average wealth or the number of people imprisoned and killed, to back this up, but of course if one is a relativist about "good" it will be no less relative with ideologies than with anything else.

Comment: @barrycarter Something which is in accord to some scientific truth/verification belief system and that has a "large enough" sample size (i.e. number of people obeying claimed belief).

Comment: @barrycarter Also, doesn't need to be fully objective, but "as good as it can be".

Comment: Science will give us statements like "animals eat, breathe, and excrete", but not "it's wrong to kill animals". I can't see an objective argument for a political ideology. As @Conifold notes, it really depends on what your measure of a "good society" is.

Comment: OK, I'm working on an answer (that I may or may not ever finish) with the premise that "The objectively perfect world is where everyone is happy all the time", and thus "the objectively best world is the world that is closest to achieving that goal"

Comment: @barrycarter Well something I've fancied lately is "consequence ethics". That is, rather than portray ideals like some contemporary political ideologues do, try to predict the consequences of different rules or actions. Those are, I think, more rational than saying "what I would like to see". Psychology and statistical questionnaires can possibly give hints about tendencies for people to exploit certain loopholes. Or also that certain policies lead to certain effects (with certain sizes), such as drug prohibition to black markets.

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but don't you then have to decide what a "good" or "bad" consequence is. At some point, you have to define objectively better for something. Even if you knew the exact consequences of everything you did, you'd have to decide which outcomes are better than others.

Comment: @barrycarter Well that's quite a difficult question, because there could exceptions to even things like "don't kill". But I believe that there's some history in law in order to have some reference for "good reasons to kill" and "bad reasons to kill". I don't know what they rely on, but possibly the amount of suffering involved or e.g. the amount of people killed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82636/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-mavavilj).

Comment: Socialism is 'utilitarian' it's objective is to improve the lot of as many people as possible. To this extent socialism also tends to be internationalist. Capitalism may also claim to be utilitarian, in that it will claim that life improves under capitalism. Yet capitalism is young and fails many.. and usually is nationalist in outlook. In my opinion any 'good' political ideology should be measured by how successfully it improves the biggest number of lives. Both inside and outside it's country of origin.

Comment: @Richard Socialism is only 'utilitarian' if you accept that everyone should be 'average': harm those who have or do more in order to help those who have or do less. It's not better objectively unless you have that subjective goal in mind.

Comment: As I said.. both left and right claim to be utilitarian.. so that's the answer. Measure a 'good' system on how utilitarian it's is. Obamacare trailer park Chinese sweatshop Nike's boy  :)

Comment: @Richard But the word "utilitarian" only makes sense  if you have a subjective purpose. By itself, utilitarianism is not objective.

Comment: It's the only metric I can think of on which everyone can agree. The job of any good political system is to improve the situation of it's citizens.